# Null reference exception during selection of comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selection

Let me explain my case. I have wpf user control in which I dynamically generate comboboxes. For this purposes I use class Control Service from which I create the comboboxes with their comboboxitems and also manage selection change event for each of them.
Everthing work great until I try to raise up second event on first combobox. There is coming problem when I try to clear items of the second combobox. I did debubugg and there is not problem with reference of combobox which I have already checked (childCmB != null), but after to try clear items of this combobox. the exception is thrown.
I try find many cases on forums but with any success, so I would appreciate any suggestion to resolve this problem.

Thank you

ControlService.class:

```
 static class ControlService
{
    private static ObservableDictionary<String, System.Windows.UIElement> controls = new ObservableDictionary<String, System.Windows.UIElement>();
    private static Grid expanderContent;

    public static Expander createExpander(String header, String name, String code)
    {
        header = manageControlName(header);
        ExpanderModelView expanderModelView = new ExpanderModelView(name);

        //Recieve template grid
        expanderContent = expanderModelView.getExpanderContent();
        //Add in static collection
        Expander expander = new Expander() { Header = header };
        //Code of provider service
        expander.Uid = code;
        expander.Name = name;

        //Set up handler
        expanderContent.AddHandler(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent, new SelectionChangedEventHandler(cmb_SelectionChanged));
        //Insert data
        expander.Content = expanderContent;

        controls.Add(header, expander);
        return expander;
    }

    public static void cleanUIElementCollection()
    {
        controls.Clear();
    }




    private static string manageControlName(string name)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        if (controls.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (String value in controls.Keys)
            {
                if (value.Equals(name))
                {
                    if (name.Any(char.IsDigit))
                        name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("("));

                    name = String.Format(name + "({0})", counter);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return name;
    }

    private static void cmb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        Grid currentContent = sender as Grid;
        String selectedItemId = ((e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Uid;
        IEnumerable<Parameter> childCmBs = DataService.getServiceParametersByParentId((e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox).Uid);

        if (childCmBs.Any())
        {
            foreach (Parameter param in childCmBs)
            {
                try
                {

                System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox childCmB = currentContent.FindName(param.Key) as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
                if (childCmB != null)
                {
                    childCmB.Items.Clear();
                    addComboBoxItems(DataService.getChildrenParameterValuesByParentId(selectedItemId), childCmB);
                }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Happen some problem during creating comboboxes: {0}", ex.Message));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void createComboBoxes(IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters, System.Windows.Controls.Panel panel)
    {
        foreach (Parameter parameter in parameters)
        {
            TextBlock cmbLabel = new TextBlock() { Text = parameter.Caption };
            System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cmb = new System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox() { Name = parameter.Key, Uid = parameter.ID };
            panel.Children.Add(cmbLabel);
            panel.Children.Add(cmb);

            addComboBoxItems(parameter.ParameterValue, cmb);
        }
    }

    public static void addComboBoxItems(IEnumerable<ParameterValue> parameterValues, System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cmb)
    { 
        foreach (ParameterValue value in parameterValues)
        {
            ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem()
            {
                Content = value.Caption,
                Uid = value.ID,
                Name = value.Key
            };
            cmb.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: which exact line gives the null reference?

Comment: In line where I try to assign variable selectedItemId. During the debug at the beginning, the variable selectedItemId is normally assigned, but when is call childCmB.Items.Clear(); the debug is returned back at the begininng of the method again and then is raised up the exception in line of variable selectedItemId.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I think the problem is this line :

```
String selectedItemId = ((e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Uid;
```

When you clear items of the combobox,

`e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem) is null`.

so, when you try to get Uid of a null item, it throws an exception.

Comment: You right but for me is strange when I did debug of this process that at the beginning the varable is assigned without any problem, but after the variable is assigned and I try to clear items of childCmB, then the debug return back at the beginning of method and then is raised up exception for variable selectedItemId.

Comment: When you debug, you pass step by step and there is a important difference of time between debugging and executing. But I can not say Something exact without debugging your code. At the and, if it helped you to resolve your problem, I am happy. And if this is the case, you can check my response as solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `SelectedItem` when you clear the `ComboBox`.

Nevertheless you should always check that a reference is valid before you try to use it. So your method should be implemented something like this:

```
private static void cmb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid currentContent = sender as Grid;
    if (currentContent != null)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = e.Source as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            ComboBoxItem selectedItem = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                String selectedItemId = selectedItem.Uid;
                IEnumerable<Parameter> childCmBs = DataService.getServiceParametersByParentId(selectedItemId);
                if (childCmBs != null && childCmBs.Any())
                {
                    foreach (Parameter param in childCmBs)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox childCmB = currentContent.FindName(param.Key) as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
                            if (childCmB != null)
                            {
                                childCmB.Items.Clear();
                                addComboBoxItems(DataService.getChildrenParameterValuesByParentId(selectedItemId), childCmB);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Happen some problem during creating comboboxes: {0}", ex.Message));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You right, after validate if the combobox or combobox item are valid and not null everything run correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow